# What programming language is this?

Tags: php, programming-languages, smarty

```
    <{if $ishtml == true}><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica" size="2"><{$contentshtml}>
<BR><BR>
<{if $settings[t_enhistory] == 1}>
<fieldset style="margin-bottom: 6px; color: #333333;FONT: 11px Verdana, Tahoma;PADDING:3px;">
<legend><{$language[tickethistory]}></legend>
<{foreach key=key value=post from=$postlist}>
<{if $post[ticketpostid] != $ticket[lastpostid]}>
<b><{$post[fullname]}></b> (<{if $post[creator] == "staff"}><{$language[thstaff]}><{elseif $post[creator] == "thirdparty"}><{$language[ththirdparty]}><{elseif $post[creator] == "recipient"}><{$language[threcipient]}><{else}><{$language[thclient]}><{/if}>) <{$language[thpostedon]}> <{$post[date]}>
<hr>
<br>
<{$post[contents]}>

<{if $ticket[hasattachments] == "1" && $post[attachmentcount] > 0}>
<BR /><BR /><fieldset style="margin-bottom: 6px; color: #333333;FONT: 11px Verdana, Tahoma;PADDING:3px;"><legend><{$language[thattachments]}></legend>
<{foreach key=attachkey value=attachment from=$post[attachments]}>
<{$attachment[filename]}> (<{$attachment[attachmentsize]}>)<BR />
<{/foreach}>
</fieldset>
<{/if}>
<br><br>
<{/if}>
<{/foreach}>
</fieldset>
<{/if}>

<fieldset style="margin-bottom: 6px; color: #333333;FONT: 11px Verdana, Tahoma;PADDING:3px;">
<legend><{$language[ticketdetails]}></legend><BR>
<{$language[articketid]}><{$ticket[fticketid]}><BR>
<{$language[ardepartment]}><{$ticket[department]}><BR>
<{$language[arpriority]}><font color="<{$priority[frcolorcode]}>"><{$ticket[priority]}></font><BR>
<{$language[arstatus]}><font color="<{$status[statuscolor]}>"><{$ticket[status]}></font><BR>
</fieldset>
</font><{else}><{$contentstext}>

<{if $settings[t_enhistory] == 1}>
<{$language[tickethistory]}>
===================
<{foreach key=key value=post from=$postlist}>
<{if $post[ticketpostid] != $ticket[lastpostid]}>
<{$post[fullname]}> (<{if $post[creator] == "staff"}><{$language[thstaff]}><{elseif $post[creator] == "thirdparty"}><{$language[ththirdparty]}><{elseif $post[creator] == "recipient"}><{$language[threcipient]}><{else}><{$language[thclient]}><{/if}>) <{$language[thpostedon]}> <{$post[date]}>

===============================================================
<{$post[contentstext]}>

<{if $ticket[hasattachments] == "1" && $post[attachmentcount] > 0}>
<{foreach key=attachkey value=attachment from=$post[attachments]}>
<{$attachment[filename]}> (<{$attachment[attachmentsize]}>)
<{/foreach}>
<{/if}>

<{/if}>
<{/foreach}>

<{/if}>
<{$language[ticketdetails]}>
===================
<{$language[articketid]}><{$ticket[fticketid]}>
<{$language[ardepartment]}><{$ticket[department]}>
<{$language[arpriority]}><{$ticket[priority]}>
<{$language[arstatus]}><{$ticket[status]}><{/if}>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd guess it's from a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/crashcourse.php) template for PHP.

Answer (score 4):

100% positive it's smarty, and the typical file extension is .tpl

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Its smarty template syntax

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some php or perl templating engine such as Mason.